# Adding a context menu in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF user control. 
In that userControl I'll have multmple WPF childControls(inherits My`BaseElement`).

I need that every ChildControl contains a specified context menu (backward, forward commands)

The code bellow does not work... What I do wrong?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ElementContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Move backward"
                  Name="back"
                  Click="back_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Move forward"
                  Name="forw"
                  Click="forw_Click" />
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:BaseElement}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
                Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ElementContextMenu}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base style isn't applied automatically to derived elements, you need to create a style for each one. Fortunately you can use style inheritance through the `BasedOn` property.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Style
    TargetType="{x:Type my:Element1DerivingFromBase}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type my:BaseElement}}" />

  <Style
    TargetType="{x:Type my:Element2DerivingFromBase}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type my:BaseElement}}" />
```